# Interesting "Interesting Tags" Bug

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching

[asmx](/questions/tagged/asmx) is one of my interesting tags. I just clicked it and noticed that several of the questions on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asmx were not highlighted.

I would have thought that the tags page for one of my interesting tags would have all the questions highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on the `/tagged/` page, then questions with that tag will not be marked as highlighted unless they have at least one other favorite (interesting) tag. Those questions will still be highlighted elsewhere.